# How can I get my pictures back from when i backed up my iphone?

Tags: itunes, backup, iphone, photos.app

I reset my iPhone 4s a couple weeks ago to see if FaceTime would start working again (it didnt!). I did back it up before I reset it, but I did not import my photos to iPhoto as I always do. Is there anyway I could get those pictures back? I haven't backed up my iPhone 4s since then.

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you have a recent backup -- so that's great news.  don't let anything over write that before you can extract your files from it.

in this case, utilities like  will let you parse through the backup files/folders and get to the photos.  these guys have a free one i just did a quick test with, and it is simple once it reads the backups and parses through it:

http://www.easeus.com/data-recovery/iphone-data-recovery/extract-iphone-data-from-itunes-backup.htm

let us know how it goes.

Comment: it has the back up folder but there are no files in the folder :(((((

Comment: Sandra, that seems very unusual.can it see any files in the backup at all?